# Use SQLite in ASP.NET MVC web application instead of SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

How to create a small ASP.NET MVC web application using SQLite database? I have tried so many ways and searched in web all of them showing using .NET Core & ASP.NET Core MVC, I don't need this.

But I need to create an ASP.NET MVC web application. I have tried by adding extension in Visual Studio 2019. I am not satisfied like using SQL Server.
I need just how to add SQLite to my ASP.NET MVC application. Please ask me if you need explanation. Please suggest a link or Youtube video. I am a beginner

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, not an ORM or data access library. Whatever library or ORM you use, use the appropriate for SQLite. As for `not satisfied like using SQL Server` why do you assume a *constrained embedded database* will be any better? You won't even be able to store dates properly, while SQL support is minimal. Since it's an embedded database, you can't have multiple connections try to modify it. Even if those are your own controllers and actions.

Comment: If you're a beginner, start by following the ASP.NET MVC tutorials in the docs, or a course. Dropping one library for another, or one database for another just because it looks difficult won't get anywhere.

Comment: You need to add the Nuget package for Sqlite to your project. Place the database file in a location that is accessible to the application, and have a connection string pointing to it. The only real difference between using sqlite and MS SQL is that with sqlite you have a file that is the database which usually is deployed along with the application in a  Data folder or similar.

Comment: can you refer any link to me to create MVC app.If there it will be very helpful to me @Crowcoder